# hive fetch result from hdfs is too slow, because of too many the map only task, How can I merge the query result When hive SQL query is executed

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

hive query produces too many result files in the fold of "/tmp/hive/hive", Close to 4W tasks.But the total number of running results is only more than 100
so I wonder if there is a way to merge the results after query, reduce the number of result files, and improve the efficiency of pulling results?

Here is the explain of the query

```
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
|                      Explain                       |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
| STAGE DEPENDENCIES:                                |
|   Stage-1 is a root stage                          |
|   Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1               |
|                                                    |
| STAGE PLANS:                                       |
|   Stage: Stage-1                                   |
|     Map Reduce                                     |
|       Map Operator Tree:                           |
|           TableScan                                |
|             alias: kafka_program_log             |
|             filterExpr: ((msg like '%disk loss%') and (ds > '2022-05-01')) (type: boolean) |
|             Statistics: Num rows: 36938084350 Data size: 11081425337136 Basic stats: PARTIAL Column stats: PARTIAL |
|             Filter Operator                        |
|               predicate: (msg like '%disk loss%') (type: boolean) |
|               Statistics: Num rows: 18469042175 Data size: 5540712668568 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: PARTIAL |
|               Select Operator                      |
|                 expressions: server (type: string), msg (type: string), ts (type: string), ds (type: string), h (type: string) |
|                 outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4 |
|                 Statistics: Num rows: 18469042175 Data size: 5540712668568 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: PARTIAL |
|                 File Output Operator               |
|                   compressed: false                |
|                   Statistics: Num rows: 18469042175 Data size: 5540712668568 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: PARTIAL |
|                   table:                           |
|                       input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat |
|                       output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat |
|                       serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe |
|                                                    |
|   Stage: Stage-0                                   |
|     Fetch Operator                                 |
|       limit: -1                                    |
|       Processor Tree:                              |
|         ListSink                                   |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Comment: set hive.merge.mapfiles = true  It does not work

Comment: Could you post the explain of the query that you are concerned about?  Maybe there is somethign that can be done.  It sounds like you are approaching this like the XY problem. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Sorry, I describe the problem I ran into. I was running Hive SQL with Beeline, but fetching the result (which actually only had 150 records, but occupied 4W files with a large number of empty result files) was very slow, so I was wondering whether there was a good solution to the problem. explain of the query has been updated in the question post, the sql is "select * from kafka_program_log where msg like "%disk loss%" and ds > '2022-05-01'"  @MattAndruff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set mapred.max.split.size=2560000000;
Increase the size of the file processed by a single map, thereby reducing the number of maps

Answer (score 0):

1. Recreate the table using ORC/Parquet and you'll get much better performance.  This is your number 1 priority for speeding things up.
2. You are using a like operator that means scanning all the data.  You may want to consider, re-writing it to use a join/where clause instead.  This will run much faster. Here's an example of what you could do to make things better.

```
    with words as --short cut for readable sub-query
    (
      select 
        log.msg 
      from 
        kafka_program_log log 
      lateral view EXPLODE(split(msg, ' ')) words as word  -- for each word in msg, make a row assumes ' disk loss ' is what is in the msg
      where 
        word in ('disk', 'loss' ) -- filter the words to the ones we care about.
      and 
        ds > '2022-05-01' -- filter dates to the ones we care about.
      group by 
        log.msg -- gather the msgs together
      having 
        count(word) >= 2  -- only pull back msg that have at least two words we are interested in.
    ) -- end sub-query
      select 
        * 
      from kafka_program_log log
      inner join 
        words.msg = log.msg  // This join should really reduce the data we examine
      where 
        msg like "%disk loss%" -- like is fine now to make sure it's exactly what we're looking for.
```

Comment: This solution does not reduce the number of maps, so this can not solve the problem I met. And I find a solution: set mapred.max.split.size=2560000000;